# find core files about where if product is out of stock redirect to cart page from checkout onepage

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, redirect, shopping-cart, out-of-stock

Just need little help,If I stay on checkout page and product is out of stock and if I process further step, magento automatically redirect cart page,now I want to find where is code in core files which is match product quantity and if qty is 0 or out of stock it redirect cart page,**Just help me to find that code which is redirect cart page from `onepage checkout` if product is `out of stock`**

I found in core files but still not find code which is redirect cart page from `onepage checkout page`.Please give me a hint please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mage_Checkout_OnepageController`

```
protected function _expireAjax()
{
    if (!$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->hasItems()
        || $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getHasError()
        || $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getIsMultiShipping()
    ) {
        $this->_ajaxRedirectResponse();
        return true;
    }
    $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
    if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getCartWasUpdated(true)
        && !in_array($action, array('index', 'progress'))
    ) {
        $this->_ajaxRedirectResponse();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

this action is called via ajax `progressAction`  this is called in `233` in

```
if ($this->_expireAjax() || !$prevStep) {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: No this code is work when click 'proceed to checkout' button from cart page but when I stay on onepage checkout page and checked register radio button and click continue button and when I click continue button that time redirect cart page that time I want to stop redirect to cart page.

Comment: that was not mention in question..

Comment: I mentioned in question that "If I stay in checkout page and I process further steps"

Comment: updated the answer...

Comment: Yes, Exactly,Thank for guide me,Just I removed $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getHasError() code from if condition in _expireAjax() function and now it is not redirect to cart page ,thanks for help,Thanks a lot once again Qaisar satti.